# hitTest not working as2

Tags: actionscript-2, output, flash-cs6, hittest

So I am making an endless runner type game, and I cannot get the hitTest to work. I have the main character just standing still, if you hit the up arrow he jumps and that all works. I also have a spike symbol that starts off screen and it has an in-symbol tween (if that makes sense) so that it comes across the screen when you get to the frame its on. 
Ive tried a lot of different ways to get the hitTest to work, but none of them are.
this is on the spike

```
onClipEvent(enterFrame){
if(_root.char.hitTest(this)){
trace("hit");
}
}
```

on the character its the same thing just replace char with spike. And yes the instance names are the same as in the code.

I have also tried _parent instead of _root. and I have tried the code not on any symbols, just on the frame like this:

```
if(_root.char.hitTest(_root.spike){
trace("hit");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a closing parentheses

```
    if(this.char.hitTest(_root.spike)**)**{
    trace("hit");                     
    }
```